# Simple past tense for unrealized hopes?

Tags: past-perfect, subjunctives, past-simple

Some grammar books say *'The past perfect can be used to express hope, wish, etc.which was not realized'*

E.g:

> 1. I *HAD hoped* we would leave tomorrow, but it won't be possible.
> 2. I *HAD meant* to call on you, but was prevented from doing so.

My question is,

If I use *past simple* instead of *past perfect* in above examples, will it express the same meaning? (or is it possible to use past simple in this case?)

Comment: The preterite "had" indicates modal remoteness (counterfactuality), but because the preterite is marking modal remoteness, it can't also be used to indicate past time, so the perfect has to be used for this purpose.

Comment: @BillJ Eh? I don't think there's a remote anywhere in either sentence; *hope* is certainly an assertion of fact, and even the *would* takes the preterit form through backshift.

Answer (score 3):

No the simple past tense is for the simple past, although it is a distinction which may be becoming blurred. Consider your first example, with just its first clause.

> I had hoped we would leave tomorrow.

It is something you don't hope any more, though, for whatever reason. Or possibly you may have hoped it, then you were told it couldn't happen, and finally you were told that the situation had changed again.  Now you can.  The point is that at some point in time between then and now you had lost hope. The past predicate would still be applicable if you regained it.

> I hoped we would leave tomorrow.

And you may well still hope that.  Just because I was happy yesterday does not mean I am not happy today. It does not mean I am happy, either. The simple past expresses nothing concerning my current state. (Well, some things are permanently permanent -- my focus is on things that can change, like emotions.)

Now simple past with both clauses:

> I hoped we would leave tomorrow, but it won't be possible.

Technically this is grammatically awkward, but it may not be wrong. You are not predicating your first clause with the meaning inherent in the second. As stated up top, this form is becoming more common as our speech becomes more, um, lazy.

Comment: If I use *past simple tense* and *perfect infinitive* in my second example, like  *'I meant to have called on you, but was...'*,  Will  it mean the same as *'I had meant to call on you, but was...'*?

Comment: I think it goes too far to say that you *can't* use the simple past to say this, since that kind of use is pretty common.  As you say, it may be *lazy* but it is perfectly natural.

Comment: @Dinusha Ouch!  That hurts my head. I think yes they mean the same, but I am not sure. I cannot think of a context where one clause would mean anything different from the other.

Comment: @Andrew I agree. That's why the persnickety old guy in me began with **No** but the realist continued the softening clause. I sense you are further along the *acceptance phase* than I. Dinusha seems to be a word nerd (like me) and wishes to know both what is "right" and what is "common".

Comment: I meant to have called = At a point in the past, I was looking ahead to what was then the future, with the expectation that I would have called upon you by that time.  :)  Spare yourself, and make the visit, so you don't have to say this.

Comment: @RichF  Well, my feeling is that this is (finally) an ideal context to use the past perfect, so why not indulge?

Comment: @TRomano ⚰ (Yes, Dinusha, please, **please** make that visit!) Thank you for the clear explanation. But is there variance in actual meaning between that and, "*I had meant to call*"? Maybe the latter does not specifically state that the call was to have been in the past's future?  I.e. it could have been in the past's present? <insert Dr. Who emoji here>

Comment: @RichF: *I had meant to call* would mean "My intention was to call you, *but something or other got in the way of my doing so*". Even with *I had meant to call you <full stop>* there would be an unspoken **but something came up**, as it were. The past perfect construction implies that there was another event, later in the past, which stood in the way of the intended call.  (I lost my phone, I forgot, the sun was in my eyes...)

Answer (score 2):

Your instinct is correct; in the most formal diction a simple past of *hope* is called for here because it represents a state that is now over and done with".

Ordinarily a past perfect must be 'anchored' on a past Reference Time which is the current topic and to which the perfect eventuality is prior. However, the sort of past perfect you have here, anchored on no evident past Reference Time, is common and in all but the most formal registers if the context implies a semantically appropriate Reference Time.

In this case the speaker thinks of his hope as a state which lasted until he discovered it was groundless, and thus lay before that discovery. The discovery is omitted in your quotation, but it may have been mentioned already:

> I learned this morning that my wife has been called in for an extra shift tomorrow night. I had hoped [i.e., until that point] that we would leave tomorrow, but it won't be possible.

And even if the discovery has not been mentioned, it is present in the speaker's mind; and most hearers will assume that some kind of obstacle became evident before the present moment.